# Regarding the connected component of $|1/J| < 1$ containing $\infty$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, modular-forms

How does one explicitly describe the connected component of $|1/J| < 1$ containing $\infty$? Here, $J = J(\tau) = j(\tau)/12^3$ is the normalized $j$-invariant so that $J(i) = 1$, and $\tau$ is in the upper half-plane.

Comment: I understand that $J$ is the image of the upper halfplane under the normalized $j$-invariant. But which set do you mean with $|1/J|$? You probably mean the set $\{\tau\in\mathbb{H}\mid|1/J(\tau)|<1\}$ where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper halfplane.

Comment: Yes, I do. That is pretty much what I have stated.

Comment: So this is just $|J|>1$?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I want something more explicit in terms of $\tau$.

Comment: @glebovg does this also come from Fricke-Klein?

Comment: @johnmangual In a way. It is from Archinard's paper "Exceptional sets of hypergeometric series" where she derives the hypergeometric representations of the periods which can be found in Fricke and Klein.